# How do I check if NDK and SDK are installed on ubuntu?

Tags: android, python, ubuntu-14.04, android-sdk-tools

What all does this command installs?

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential ccache git zlib1g-dev python2.7 python2.7-dev libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386 openjdk-7-jdk unzip ant
```

Also list the steps to follow to install the latest NDK and SDK on Ububtu 14.04 LTS and set their path variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will install python2.7 , openjava 7 and c++ libraries